# why the JavaScript Not running?

Tags: javascript, html

in this code if I put form="form" in the button JavaScript function not running in if i remove it it running normal .but the action of the form didn't work

```
 <div class="form">
  <form id="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
    <label> Name</label><br><br>
    <input name ="name" type="text" ><br><br>
    <label> Age</label><br><br>
    <input name ="age" type="text" ><br><br>
    <label> Gender</label><br><br>
    <input name ="gender" type="text" ><br><br>
    <label>Your Photo</label>><br><br>


  </form>
    <input type="file" class="imag" id="file" name="file">
   <button id="insert"   onclick="return uploadfile();" >submit</button>

</div>
```

And this is the JavaScript functions

```
  var selectedFile;
   $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#file").on("change",function(event){
        selectedFile =event.target.files[0];
        console.log(selectedFile);
        });
    });


    function uploadfile()
    {
            // Create a reference to 'images/mountains.jpg'
        var filename=selectedFile.name;
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/'+'/'+filename );
        var uploadTask=storageRef.put(selectedFile);

        uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){

        }, function(error) {

        }, function() {
            var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
            console.log(downloadURL);
        });


    }
```

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: Well...why are your button and file input outside the form to begin with?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder He doesn't want the file to be uploaded to the form target, he just wants it put in Firebase.

Comment: @Barmar: That doesn't mean the button should be outside the form and the related to it with `form=` (as your answer explains).

Comment: Inside or outside is mostly irrelevant, the issue is whether it's associated with the form or not.

Comment: @Barmar Yes indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `form="form"` to the button, clicking on it submits the form, which reloads the page, and that stops any Javascript that's running. So the `uploadfile()` function is stopped before it can upload the file.

You should change `uploadfile()` so that it submits the form with

```
document.getElementById("form").submit();
```

after `uploadTask` completes.

Comment: Fair enough. Mind you, it's unclear what purpose putting the pseudo-filename in firebase serves.